# Adding googlecalendar events in an android application

Tags: android

I'm a newbie to android programming and have been trying to add events to google calendar via an android application. I found a nice example on the web but cannot seem to get the code to run as the application crashes as soon as the emulator launches. I'm emulating the code on the ANDROID DEVICE (Google APIs/API LEVEL 14).Below is the URL of the code;

http://roman10.net/src/calendarops.zip

Here are the errors which I receive in the logcat;

```
    12-21 15:24:16.602: D/AndroidRuntime(675): Shutting down VM
```

`12-21 15:24:16.612: W/dalvikvm(675): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught     exception (group=0x409961f8)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{roman10.tutorial.calendarops/roman10.tutorial.calendarops.Main}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: displayName: , while compiling: SELECT _id, displayName FROM Calendars

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: displayName: , while compiling: SELECT _id, displayName FROM Calendars

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:358)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:310)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1706)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at roman10.tutorial.calendarops.Main.getCalendars(Main.java:127)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at roman10.tutorial.calendarops.Main.onCreate(Main.java:50)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)

12-21 15:24:16.622: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  ... 11 more`

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace or the LogCats log?

Comment: I've edited my original post and included the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: displayName:
>   , while compiling: SELECT _id, displayName FROM Calendars

There is no column with the name 'displayName' in your Calendars table.

Comment: There is no workaround? You should adjust your select statement to match the columns name. Assuming you know SQL. If not, I advise you to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ICS (SDK 14) they have changed the way they handle Calanders and have made a public API. See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/ics-and-non-public-apis.html

Comment: oops ICS is 15 :-) might still have the new way of doing it